# Wordpress Defaults to HTTP 1.0

Tags: wordpress, http

If  you look at the documentation for [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) you see that the arguments array takes an http version, but defaults to "1.0". Why is the default not "1.1" in WordPress?

Is there any risk in me consistently passing "1.1" to take advantage of the newer version of http?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1

Comment: @vtortola I know the differences. I am asking WHY WordPress is defaulting to 1.0. It is widely used software so I assume there is a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 1.1 requests are pipelined by default. If you don't "Connection: Close", it assumes "Connection: Keep-Alive", and then you have to wait for the connection to time out (since you never explicitly closed it) before the next loop will start.

Answered by TML -> [file_get_contents() with context to use http/1.1 significantly slow download speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485843/file-get-contents-with-context-to-use-http-1-1-significantly-slow-download-spe)

To avoid the risk of getting slowed down to get the response using HTTP 1.1, you must pass header connection close in wp_remote_get :

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.php?action=foo',
    array(
        'timeout'     => 120,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'headers'     => 'Connection: close'
         )
);
```